# I don't have delete option under my question in stackexchange

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

How to have delete option under my question in stackexchange?

Answer (score 6):

You weren't able to delete your question:

[How to execute the following commands at once in ubuntu using postgresql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/133906/1) (original title)

...because you are using a **cookie-based (unregistered) account**.

This is explained in the Stack Exchange FAQ:

[Why should I register my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44562/194636)

> ...the site prevents unregistered users [from deleting their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50260/new-unregistered-users-should-be-able-to-delete-their-own-answers/50271#50271).

From the quoted link:

> If you want to delete posts (remember, a delete is considered a *vote*) then you have to use a **registered** account.
>
> Cookie-based accounts don't support voting, therefore they don't support deletion.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure which question you are talking about, but both your previous question have an upvoted and accepted answer.

From the help center [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes

So you can't delete your question yourself anymore because it has an upvoted answer. If you have good reasons to want the question gone, you can always flag it for moderator intervention and explain why.

That being said, I don't think any of your 2 previous questions should be deleted just because you got your answer. This site is more than a personal support forum, it's also meant to help others who face the same problem.

EDIT: As @PaulWhite pointed out you weren't talking about one of your previous questions but about this one before you destructively edited you own question. Please don't do that.